# get text file content using python. and question about matplotlib syntax

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, text

if I have a text file called vertices.txt formatted this way :

```
5       //this is the number of vertices "V"
1, 10  // these are the x,y coordinates of each vertices so this is for vertice 0
8, 10  // coordinates for 1
10, 8  // coordinates for 2
7, 4   // coordinates for 3
3, 1   // coordiantes for 4. I need the coordinates as I will later plot them using matplotlib
0,1,10 // i, j, k tells you that there is an edge between vi and vj and its weight is k.
1,2,5  // v1,v2,5 and so on for the rest 
2,3,25
0,3,3
3,4,8
```

**note:**
in the .txt file the first line is the number of vertices "V". and lines from line 2 to line V+1 are the x,y coordinates for each vertices.
and Lines from line number V+2 to the last line give information about the edges of
the graph i,j,k

and I want to get the coordinates x and y in a variable and the edges in a variable so i did this:

```
fr = open('vertices.txt', 'r')
myarray=[]
tempreadintomemory= fr.read()
myarray= tempreadintomemory.splitlines()
print('temp',tempreadintomemory)
print ('myarray',myarray)

numOfVertices=myarray[0]
print(int(numOfVertices)+1)

cor = myarray[1:int(numOfVertices)+1]
print('cor',cor)

myedges=[]
myedges= myarray[int(numOfVertices) + 1:]
print('edges', myedges)
xx=myedges[1].split(",")
print('splitedges',xx)
print('weight',xx[2])

weights=[]
xx=[]
i = 0
while i < len(myedges):
    xx = myedges[i].split(",")
    weights.append(xx[2])
    i += 1
print('the weights',weights)
```

but i want to get the myedges to be formated this way ['i','j',k] where i and j to be strings and k to be int

also i'm trying to get the coordinates to be in this formats
xCor=[1,8,10,7,3]
yCor=[10,10,8,4,1]
so what should I change in my code?

Comment: Please post the second question as a separate question. Also, you may want to have a look at [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: You should indeed keep it to one question per post. I also echo that networkx is the way to go. You seem to be dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you instead edit your question to ask "I have these vertices and edges, how do I plot the last image", it'll be an improvement. Assuming that's your actual goal.

Comment: thank you for your advice I edited out the second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't plotting how you might think it is plotting.  You're basically tracing a line from one coordinate to the next.  What you actually want to do is create a number of line segments between each of your vertices as defined by your edges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

def create_vertices_text(coord,i):
    return ax.text(coord[0],coord[1], 'V'+str(i))

data = []
with open('vertices.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data.append([int(elem) for elem in line.strip().split(',')])

edges = []
vertices = []

for row in data[1:]:
    if len(row) > 2:
        edges.append(row)
    if len(row) == 2:
        vertices.append(row)

x_cor = [elem[0] for elem in vertices]
y_cor = [elem[1] for elem in vertices]

mylines = [(vertices[edge[0]], vertices[edge[1]]) for edge in edges]

lc = mc.LineCollection(mylines, colors=['k']*len(mylines), linewidths=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
for i in range(len(vertices)):
     create_vertices_text(vertices[i],i)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that I don't actually use x_cor or y_cor variables.  You could delete them.  That was answering part of your question about how to get a list of x_coordinates and y_coordinates.